# Does Cypress clear the browser cache before each test?

Tags: cypress

Cypress [clears all cookies](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearcookies.html) and [local storage](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage.html) before each test. Does it also clear the browser's file cache?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by 'browser cache'? What  is the issue you're trying to fix or feature you're trying to test exactly?

Comment: I'm thinking of the memory or disk based file cache that the browser uses for html, js and other files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**EDIT:** Cypress automatically clears browser cache before the browser launches in [Version 0.20.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1124). So, the cache will be cleared between each spec file is run.

No, Cypress does not clear browser cache before each test. Cypress respects the cache headers of your server. So if they are set, the browser will cache those files. This isn't really documented anywhere exactly, but I'm a developer at Cypress so know this is how it works.

If you want to see some different behavior, I suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new) on the OS Cypress project.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, I've the same need as Arne so I've opened an issue on the OS Cypress project: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1124 .
I would be glad of take care of it if anyone of this project accept it as an welcome contribution :)

Comment: Can i save cache whenever change spec file ? Because a lot of image on website any solution?

Answer (score -6):

**No, by default Cypress does not clear the browser cache before each test**.
However, you can clear the browser cache manually in your tests by using the `cy.clearCookies()` and `cy.clearLocalStorage()` commands.

For example, you can add the following code to your test to clear the browser cache before each test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.exec('localStorage.clear()');
  cy.exec('sessionStorage.clear()');
  cy.clearCookies();
});
```

[Clear Cypress Cache](https://clearcachefilesincypress.blogspot.com/2021/06/how-to-clear-cache-files-in-cypress.html)

Comment: Sadly, no it's not the same cache.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, the question was very specific as to clearing browser cache.