# Cypress cache - server session expired

Tags: cypress

Can Cypress clear browser cookies/cache before each test?

The problem I am experiencing is the first execution is ok, but the second fails due to the cache. I tried `cy.clearCookies()`, but it doesn't work.

During the second execution, I receive the message `server session expired`.

Comment: can Cypress clear browser cookie/cache before each test?

Comment: Hmm `cy.clearCookies()` worked for me in some cases, but since I also had a problem with state not clearing between cases - with my team we decided I would never put more than one case per test file and group them in folders. Try this approach.

Comment: No, there's no way to clear cache programmatically. Cypress only clears the cache upon opening the browser, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47187328/8754516).

Answer (score 0):

Though I think by default each `it` block starts with a clear cache. The following command may be useful for your purposes

```
cy.clearLocalStorage()
```

Doc here:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage#Command-Log

You could possibly wrap this like so

```
before(function () {
cy.clearLocalStorage();
});

describe("Some useful description", () => {
// your 'it' blocks here
})
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to programmatically clear your cache after each test, try:

```
describe("Some useful description", () => {

 afterEach(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorage()
});

// your 'it' blocks here
})
```