# How to let Cypress-tests bypass all caches (Varnish, Redis, etc.)

Tags: caching, redis, cypress, e2e-testing, varnish

On a site, I have a caching infrastructure like this:

- Redis cache, to cache database-queries.
- Varnish cache, to cache application responses (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.).
- Browser cache ([Cypress clears this between each test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47187328/1766219) - so far, so good!).

After a deploy, I would like to receive a 'fresh' and uncached version of the site *for my Cypress-tests*. I don't want to clear the cache for all visitors. I just want my Cypress-tests to see an uncached version, after a deploy.

My idea was add a header to all my `cy.visit` and `cy.request`, and then setting up my Varnish-cache settings, to look for that. And handling it in Redis as well.

It appears to be quite cumbersome, but doable, to actually do this 'bypass-cache'-setup in Varnish and Redis. If anyone has a better/simpler way of doing this, I'm all ears.

What the core of this question is: 'How do I send a header with all my `cy.visit` and `cy.request`, without having to type it out like this, every time (see below)?

```
cy.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://example.org',
  headers: {
    'x-my-custom-header': 'myValue'
  }
}).then((response) => {
  // ... 
});

cy.visit('/', {
  headers: {
    'x-my-custom-header': 'myValue'
  }});
```

---

### My solution considerations

I considered building my own custom command on top of this. But it gets long-tailed and clumbsy quickly.

I also considered, if I could intercept all requests and add the header to it, in `beforeEach` in my `e2e.js`. I couldn't get this to work, though. This was my attempt:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
    req.headers['x-foo'] = 'bar';
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Requests issued from the test (handled with intercept)**

You haven't mentioned the problem with the intercept, just that there is one. If there are other intercepts in the pipeline, the `middleware` option ensures the headers are added before those other intercepts are called.

[Passing a request to the next request handler](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Passing-a-request-to-the-next-request-handler)

```js
// you could have a top-level middleware handler that
// sets an auth token on all requests
// but remember setting `middleware: true` will
// cause this to always be called first
cy.intercept('http://api.company.com/', 
  { middleware: true },              <--  don't block the intercepts in the tests
  (req) => {
    req.headers['authorization'] = `token ${token}`
  }
)
```

**Example**

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept('*', { middleware: true }, (req) => {
    req.headers['x-nocache'] = '123'
  }).as('header-added')
})

it('/todos/1 with additional header', () => {

  cy.intercept('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .as('wait-for-response')

  cy.window().then(win => win.fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))

  cy.wait('@wait-for-response')
    .its('request')
    .its('headers')
    .its('x-nocache')
    .should('eq', '123')
})

it('/todos/2 with additional header', () => {

  cy.window().then(win => win.fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2'))

  cy.wait('@header-added')
    .its('request')
    .its('headers')
    .its('x-nocache')
    .should('eq', '123')
})
```

[image]

---

**Requests issued from the test (not handled by intercept)**

Using a custom command to add header to all `cy.request()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("request", (originalFn, ...args) => {
  const {_} = Cypress
  const isMethod = (a) => ['GET','POST','PUT','PATCH','DELETE'].includes(a)

  let options = { headers: {} }
  if (_.isObject(args[0])) {
    _.extend(options, args[0])
  } else if (args.length === 1) {
    options.url = args[0]
  } else if (args.length === 2 && isMethod(args[0])) {
    options.method = args[0]
    options.url = args[1]
  } else if (args.length === 2 && _.isObject(args[1])) {  
    options.url = args[0]
    options.body = args[1]
  } else if (args.length === 3) {
    options.method = args[0]
    options.url = args[1]
    options.body = args[2]
  }

  options.headers['x-nocache'] = '123'
  return originalFn(options)
})

cy.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3')
  .its('requestHeaders').should('have.property', 'x-nocache', '123')

cy.request({url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3', headers:{'x-other': 'abc'}}) 
  .its('requestHeaders')
  .should(requestHeaders => {
    expect(requestHeaders['x-nocache']).to.eq('123')
    expect(requestHeaders['x-other']).to.eq('abc')
  })
```

[image]